# How would you auto format hyperlinks using meteor

Tags: hyperlink, meteor

I am working on a chat room application and would like to auto format hyperlinks so they can be visited without copy/paste.

I found autolink.js and was able to get it to work using a static HTML template but have not been able to get it working with meteor.

Any suggestions?

Edit -

Meteor Version 0.6.1

Chatroom Application - https://github.com/SmashBrando/chatroom

Autolink.js - https://github.com/bryanwoods/autolink-js

(this is not setup as it did not work)

Comment: Add the code that isn't working to this question. Tell us what problem/error you are having. And which version of Meteor are you using?

Comment: Updated - See above (added code)

Comment: change the code you've uploaded to show us where/how you're currently trying to use autolink

Comment: added autolink example with in the github repo

Comment: Live example including resolution - http://smashchat.meteor.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in the helper you want to display the hyperlink. Assuming you've got the autolink.js all set up in your `/client/lib` folder just use it with your helper

e.g

**client js**

```
Template.hello.greeting = function() {
    return "This is a link to Google http://google.com".autoLink()
}
```

and you need to make sure your HTML uses handlebars that can give html output (thats with 3 curly braces either side instead of 2):

**html in your template**

```
{{{greeting}}}
```

This should output

```
This is a link to Google <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>
```

---

#### Using transform to autolink on cursors

When using a handlebars helper that returns a cursor such as `Messages.find()` in your code you need to `transform` your collection. So with your code you need to alter the return value:

```
Template.messages.messages = function () {
    return Messages.find({}, { sort: {time: -1}, transform: function(doc) {
        if(doc.message) doc.message = doc.message.autoLink()
            return doc;
        }
    });
};
```

A [transform changes](http://docs.meteor.com/#collections) the documents in your collection, so in the above each one's message is autoLinked.

You also need to let let handlebars display this as clickable links by altering your handlebars for the HTML to use 3 curly braces to make sure your 's aren't escaped.:

```
<template name="message">
<p><strong>{{name}}:</strong> {{{message}}}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I will commit the changes to github for others to use :)

Comment: FYI I have added an example here - http://smashchat.meteor.com/

It would be great if the community contributed to making it awesome.

Comment: Just curious, any methods that don't involve triple braces?